# How to fix Outlook 365 desktop client sending emails one hour ahead

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have an Outlook 365 desktop client on Windows 10 which for every email sent has the date one hour ahead.

It would appear this is a daylight savings issue however the clock on the computer is correct, mails sent via the Gmail web interface come through fine so it's something to do with the Outlook client.

I've checked the timezone in the Outlook calendar settings and that's correct, however there's no checkbox for obeying DST changes which a search of the internet suggests will resolve it.

An example Date header

`Date: Thu, 3 May 2018 12:42:38 +0100`

This was actually sent at `Thu, 3 May 2018 11:42:38 +0100`

Comment: Check the value in Settings -> Options -> Settings -> Regional -> Current time zone. Is that client in the same time-zone as you? Do others in the same time zone as the client also see a wrong hour?

Comment: Yes the current time zone is correct if an email is sent from outlook to someone in the same time zone it appears as the correct time zone but one hour ahead.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that for that one client the time zone setting in his Microsoft personal info account is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix turned out to be this, not entirely sure which part fixed it

1. Disable setting the time/date automatically
2. Disable setting the timezone automatically
3. Enable the windows time service
4. Enable setting the time/date automatically
5. Enable setting the timezone automatically

No idea why this only effected outlook and not the windows system clock.